# display star rating using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am displaying star rating on html from database. when rating=3 then first 3 star in orange color rest in grey color. I am doing following code. It will give all star in orange color.

```
 <?php
                        $stars_count=$re->rating;
                        $count=1;
                        for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
                        {
                        if($stars_count >= $count)
                        {
                        ?>
                         <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" style="color:orange"></i>
                       <?php 
                         }
                         else
                         {
                        ?>
                         <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" style="color:grey"></i>
                        <?php
                         } 
                        }
                        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need the $count variable at all, because you have one count variable ($i) in your loop, and you should compare the $star_count with that.

```
<?php    
    $stars_count = $re->rating;
                    
    for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
        if($stars_count >= $i)
        {
            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" style="color:orange">Orange</i>
            <?php 
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
                <i class="fa fa-star fa-2x" style="color:grey">Gray</i>
            <?php
               
        } 
    }
?>
```